# Convert temporary vector to list in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I have a function `get_stuff()` that returns a `vector`.
I would like to do the following:

```
vector<int> get_stuff();  // a function returning a vector of ints

list<int> stuff = get_stuff();
```

`stuff` has to be a list because there will be a lot of insert/delete operations.

However you obviously can't assign a `vector` to a `list`, neither use it as a constructor argument.

Also, I would rather not just change the return type of `get_stuff` to `list` because in other parts of the code I need random access over what `get_stuff` returns, hence I need a `vector`.

The obvious way would be this:

```
vector<int> get_stuff();  // a function returning a vector of ints

vector<int> stuff_temp = get_stuff();

list<int> stuff(stuff_temp.begin(), stuff_temp.end());
```

But I'd rather not pollute the code with unnecessary variables unless absolutely necessary.

Is there a nicer way of getting the return values of `get_stuff` into the list `stuff`, ideally in one line?

Comment: Can't `get_stuff` just return a `list`? Concerning unnecessary variables: You could just wrap the whole thing in a helper function `std::list<int> get_stuff_as_list()` or something.

Comment: I'm more curious about the reason you need a list to begin with. What is the original problem you want to solve? Why do you need a list to solve that problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As I said in the question. There will be a lot of deletions. In order to keep the code clean the deletions will be separated from the code that populates the container (whatever that container might be). Also, in order to keep the code clean, the multiple conditions that can lead to an element being filtered out will be separated. Hence this will lead to quite a bit of random-access deletions.

Comment: If you have a massive list, then insertion/deletion in a `std::list` is more efficient that `std::vector` right? because you need to push/pull from insert/delete position to end?

Comment: While `std::vector` should normally be the "go to" container type, maybe it's not the best option to begin with here? Perhaps you should start out with a list, and avoid all the copying between container types? Or perhaps consider the "in between" (kind of) `std::deque`?

Comment: @Roy2511 Yes, exactly! Deletion and insertion on a vector are both O(n), so an algorithm that uses them alot is gonna be O(n^2), however if the algorithm has O(1) insert/delete then the entire thing is only O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lambda like this:

```
std::list<int> oList = [](std::vector<int>&& v){ return std::list<int>(v.begin(), v.end()); }(get_stuff());
```

The line can be written a little shorter:

```
auto oList = [](std::vector<int>&& v){ return std::list<int>(v.begin(), v.end()); }(get_stuff());
```

And with C++14 more shorter:

```
auto oList = [](auto&& v){ return std::list<int>(v.begin(), v.end()); }(get_stuff());
```

Comment: Would a range-for work as well? `list<int> stuff; for ( int i : get_stuff() ) stuff.push_back( i );`?

Comment: @DevSolar, yes, you can use range-for loop this way, but not this one: 
`for( int i : get_stuff().some_func() ) { /* .. */ }`
See [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Answer (score -2):

Something like this might work... No extra variables other than the temp one.. :)

```
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
list<int> l(3);
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), l.begin());
```

Comment: I have already talked about this in the question. I would like not to use temporary variables. Give the question another read :)

Answer (score -4):

I decided to use a template:

```
template <typename CONTAINER_TYPE> 
CONTAINER_TYPE get_stuff() 
{
    CONTAINER_TYPE output;
    output.push_back(thing1);
    output.push_back(thing2);
    output.push_back(thing2);
    return output;
}

list<int> stuff = get_stuff<list<int>>();
```

This gives all the advantages I need. Errors get throws at compile time if the container type does not support the operations I need and it can use any container.

Comment: How would this work, if `get_stuff()` returns a vector as posited in your question?

Comment: This is not an answer to your own question.

Comment: @DevSolar sorry! I thought it was clear enough, I made an edit with a mock of how the inside of the function looks.

Comment: You **do** realize that, once you write this not as a mockup but an actual working solution, that you'd **still** be using a temporary variable (*plus* a function call *plus* several lines of unnecessary source)? How is this a "solution" to your problem?

Comment: @DevSolar I might be misunderstanding what you mean. `get_stuff()` basically looks the same, I replaced `vector<thing>` with the template `CONTAINER_TYPE` and changed basically nothing. So the issue I described appears solved since I do not need an extra variable now and can just assign the function result to my `list`. Did I miss or misunderstand something?

Comment: Oh... you mean this is rewriting *the original `get_stuff()` itself, which had before been returning `vector<int>`? If you have control over that function, why didn't you make that function return `list<int>` in the first place (as the very first comment by churill asked you)? Sorry, if that is what you wanted to present here, your question is already very poorly worded. Voting to close as "unclear".

Comment: @DevSolar sorry if it was unclear, I'll try to reword it, no problem. And yes, I do have control, but the `get_stuff` function will be used in multiple places in the API and in some of those places the result needs random access (aka `vector`).